# gson.fromJson can't convert the json string into array

Tags: android, gson

In an Android application,
I try to convert a json string into array

```
 mJsonString = {"J":[{"a":"G-CDS","b":"1"}]};
 ArrayList<CTable_RawData_DataClass> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Type mType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CTable_RawData_DataClass>>(){}.getType();
 mArrayList = gson.fromJson(mJsonString, mType);
```

Where CTable_RawData_DataClass is as following:

```
public class CTable_RawData_DataClass {
    String a; // C_ID;
    String b; // C_Data;
    public CTable_RawData_DataClass()
    {
    }

    public String getC_ID() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setC_ID(String name) {
        this.a = name;
    }

    public String getC_Data() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setC_Data(String name) {
        this.b = name;
    }
}
```

when `mJsonString = [{"a":"G-CDS","b":"1"}];` there is no problem but

when `mJsonString = {"J":[{"a":"G-CDS","b":"1"}]};` it's not working

How can I convert `{"J":[{"a":"G-CDS","b":"1"}]}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a POJO like this:

```
-----------------------------------yourpackage.J.java-----------------------------------

package yourpackage;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class J {

@SerializedName("a")
@Expose
private String a;
@SerializedName("b")
@Expose
private String b;

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
*
*/
public J() {
}

/**
*
* @param a
* @param b
*/
public J(String a, String b) {
super();
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
}

public String getA() {
return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
this.a = a;
}

public String getB() {
return b;
}

public void setB(String b) {
this.b = b;
}

}
-----------------------------------yourpackage.UsablePOJO.java-----------------------------------

package yourpackage;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UsablePOJO{

@SerializedName("J")
@Expose
private List<J> j = null;

/**
* No args constructor for use in serialization
*
*/
public UsablePOJO() {
}

/**
*
* @param j
*/
public UsablePOJO(List<J> j) {
super();
this.j = j;
}

public List<J> getJ() {
return j;
}

public void setJ(List<J> j) {
this.j = j;
}

}
```